# Testcafe - Is it possible (should it be possible) to record video with portable browsers?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, video-capture, testcafe

I have one simple (or two) question(s): Is it possible to record videos with a portable browser of Edge? Also, is it in general possible to record videos with portable browsers of which video recording support exist? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To record a video with a portable browser, you need to specify the browser alias explicitly instead of the word "path":

`testcafe edge:e:/tools/edge-portable/msedge.exe test.js --video video-artigacts`.

Note that video recording is supported in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and Microsoft Edge (Chromium-based). TestCafe cannot record videos when you run tests in [remote browsers](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402828/guides/concepts/browsers#browsers-on-remote-devices).

Comment: Thank you. By the way, is this documented in Testcafe docs? Otherwise I think it would be good to document it. Because I could not find this information.

Comment: The way I suggested is not described in the documentation. Thank you for your comment, I've created an issue to add this information to the topic about portable browsers: [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6699](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6699)